# About Wald's equation, why can't I simply use total expectation to prove?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Wald's equation: for i.i.d r.v $X_i$, if $N$ is a stopping time, then:
$$E \sum_{i=1}^N X_i = E[N] E[X_1]$$

I just read this equation, but it seems to me if I do:
$$E \sum_{i=1}^N X_i =E_N [\sum_{i=1}^N X_i|N]=E_N[NEX_i]=E[N]E[X_1]$$

I don't know what's wrong with this proof. But in this proof it does not use the fact that $N$ is stopping time.

Comment: Please reference your book and page number. Wald, the physicist, has written several books

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wald's identity fails if $N$ and $X_i$ are too strongly coupled to one another. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald's_equation) gives a nice example to illustrate this point: if you have a sequence of iid Bernoulli(1/2) variables $X_n$, and you set $N=1-X_1$, then $E \left [ \sum_{i=1}^N X_i \right ] = 0$ (because the sum is either empty or a sum of a single zero) but $E[N]E[X_i]=1/4$.

That said, with no additional assumptions, you can write this:

$$E \left [ \sum_{i=1}^N X_i \right ] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty E \left [ \left. \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right | N=n \right ] P(N=n).$$

You can also use linearity of conditional expectation to get

$$E \left [ \sum_{i=1}^N X_i \right ] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i \mid N=n] P(N=n).$$

But you cannot replace $E[X_i \mid N=n]$ by $E[X_i]$, unless you have some independence-type hypothesis. (For instance, in Wikipedia's example, $E[X_i \mid N=0]=1$ and $E[X_i \mid N=1]=0$.)