# Expected value of sum of a random variable where the upper limit is a random variable.

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Consider $X_i$ to denote the numerical value for the i-th event. Assume it is IID.

Say we want to compute

$$
c = E\left[\sum_{i=1}^NX_i\right]
$$

$N$ is a random variable. You can think of it as represent the number of events needed to get some constant sum $c$. My question is, can the above be simplified in the following manner?

$$
c = \sum_{i=1}^NE[X_i] \\
= NE[X_i]
$$

Comment: On second thought, this doesn't make sense. The LHS is a constant and the RHS is a random variable. Could I change $N$ to $E[N]$?

Comment: @shibai Yup, I just realized this too.... Is it valid to replace all the $N$ with $E[N]$?

Comment: The question is confusing. If $N$ is the minimum number of tries st $\sum_{i=1}^N X_i \ge c$, then you should use another letter for $d = E[\sum_{i=1}^N X_i]$

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536134/about-walds-equation-why-cant-i-simply-use-total-expectation-to-prove

Comment: @leonbloy The particular I have in mind is $N$ is the number of trials needed for $c$ successes in a bernoulli trial. For example, number of trials, $N$, to get $c=3$ heads for a $N$ tosses.

Comment: [Wald's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation)

Comment: @RobPratt For my particular examples, it seems Wald's equation would not work since $N$ and $X_i$ are not independent?

Comment: @student010101, the Wikipedia page discusses some cases where independence is not required.

Answer (score 3):

Since the $X_i$ are i.i.d., say they have mean $\mathbb E[X_i]=\mu$.
For a fixed $n$ (not random) we would get $\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right]=n\mu$ by linearity.
Now, suppose $N$ is random (under some sort of well-defined distribution), then I'm going to assume that

- $N$ is independent of the $X_i$ (for example, $N$ isn't determined by continuing to sample the $X_i$ until it achieves a certain value)
- you perform the trial $X_i$ for *all* $i=1,2,3,\dots$ and sample $N$ before taking the sum

Under these assumptions,
$$
\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^NX_i\right] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb E\underbrace{\left[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right]}_{=n\mu}\operatorname{Pr}(N=n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\operatorname{Pr}(N=n)\cdot\mu = \mathbb E[N]\cdot\mu
$$
In the first and last step, I used the definition of expectation (i.e., $\mathbb E[f(X)] = \sum_{x\in\Omega}f(x)\operatorname{Pr}(X=x)$ where $\Omega$ is the space of possible values of $X$).

Comment: Hmm so if say $N$ is the number of tosses of a fair coin to get $c = 3$ heads, then it seems this would break your assumptions, if I understand correctly? Because $N$ would depend on $X_i$?

Comment: Also what in the name of the property you used for the first equality? I want to say it looks like law of total expectation, but it's not in a familiar form to me. It seems that you are conditioning over all possible values of $N$.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer to explain my computations. As for your first comment, yes if the $X_i$ were modelling coin flips and $N$ were determined by the behaviour of the coins, then this would not work; you would have to be more careful how you manipulate th expectations

Comment: Could you expand on how to manipulate the expectations for this coin case? It actually seems the formula in the answer gives the correct answer, but it is probably just due to chance? For example consider $c = 3$, then we would expect $E[N] = 6$. Or if $c = m$, then $E[N] = 2 * m$. This is exactly what your answer gives.

Comment: You have to be careful how you define things here. If $N$ is defined to be the smallest number so that $c$ coin flips happen in the first $N$ trials, then $\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^NX_i\right]$ is going to be equal to $c$ by the very definition of $N$ (this is the expectation of a _constant_ random variable).

Comment: If I set $N=1$ if $X_3=1$ and $N=2$ if $X_3=0$, then $\mathbb E[N]=\frac12$ and $\mathbb E[N]\mathbb E[X]=\frac14$, but the expectation of the sum works out to be $\mathbb E[X_1+X_2]\operatorname{Pr}(X_3=0) + \mathbb E[X_1]\operatorname{Pr}(X_3=1) = \frac34$ (assuming a fair coin)

Comment: I'm not sure if I explained clearly but I defined $N$ to be the number of coin clips required to get $c$ heads out of the $N$ tosses. $N$ is not defined to be the smallest number so that $c$ heads happen first, because that would just be $c$?